# Set cookie when sending request using cURL

Tags: javascript, php, curl

There is an external website A (not mine) which provides a PDF document after filling an HTML form.
Here is the scenario when I do the procedure on site A :

- I open my Internet browser on the site A homepage (I will call this
  page A1), then a JESSIONID is created into my browser's cookie
- I fill the form on a page A2
- if the form is correctly filled, i am    redirected to a page A3,
  from which a link is available to download a    PDF file, using url :
  A.com/getPdf.jsp

I now want to allow users to dowload this PDF file from my website B, using my own form.
To do so :

- step 1 : I am sending the form inputs to website A using PHP cURL.
  This step is working successfully, and I got a JSESSIONID reference.
- step 2 : then I am opening a window from my website using URL :
  A.com/getPdf.jsp

But it does not provide me the needed document as the session state is not maintained between previous steps 1 and 2...

So my question is to know how can I call A.com/getPdf.jsp URL, using the same state (same JESSIONID) than the one I retrieved just before from the cURL request?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: store it in a $_SESSION variable, or add it as a hidden input variable of your own form?

Comment: There is no way to set a cookie for a third-party website in you user's browser. The only way would be to download the PDF to your server and then make it accessible for your user from there.